# AWS Lambda error (module initialization error: name 'dynamodb' is not defined) with dynamodb

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-iot, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I'm trying to run a lambda function that takes an `attribute` about the AWS IoT Dash button, its `serialNumber`, and queries it in DynamoDB. Consequently, it is supposed to print the entire row.

Here is the code --->

```
from __future__ import print_function
import boto3
import json
import decimal
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr

def lambda_handler(event, context):
print ('Init 1Push_Care_DATAprint')
print (event)
serialNumber = event['serialNumber']

class DecimalEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, decimal.Decimal):
            if o % 1 > 0:
                return float(o)
        else:
            return int(o)
return super(DecimalEncoder, self).default(o)

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb',region_name='us-east-1')

table = dynamodb.Table('1Push_Care_USERinfo')

response = table.query(
KeyConditionExpression=Key('Device_ID').eq('serialNumber')
)
items = response['Items']
print(items)
```

Here is the error message I keep receiving --->

```
module initialization error: name 'dynamodb' is not defined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the error was appearing was stupid. The simple solution was to simply eliminate some tabs. Backspace them so everything has proper indentation.